# Dividing numbers stored in a varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I am in need of the experts' assistance on how to divide varchar in Postgres

I have two columns, "Price" and "Sq_Ft". Price has a dollar sign attached and contains commas while Sq_Ft only contains commas.

```
"Price"             "Sq_Ft"                    
$352,900             3,478
$357,630             3,587
$445,360             1,589
```

What is the most viable approach to tackle this issue and divide the two varchar values?

Comment: You should **not** store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: What if the numbers have $ (dollar sign) and commas? Integer data type fails.

Comment: Prices should be stored as `decimal` with the currency stored in a separate column.

Comment: So decimal data type can store commas, then. I did not know that. Thanks A horse with no name.

Comment: If with "comma" you mean the decimal separator, then yes. If you mean a "thousands group separator" then the answer is no. In short numbers (and date or timestamp) are stored **without** any format. You apply the format when you _display_ the values.

Comment: 345,000 I mean this. So how can I remove the comma?

Comment: You just store `345000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  "Price"::money / to_number("Sq_Ft",'99999999999')
from    t
;
```

---

```
+---------+
| $101.47 |
+---------+
| $99.70  |
+---------+
| $280.28 |
+---------+
```

or

```
select  to_number("Price",'99999999999') / to_number("Sq_Ft",'99999999999')
from    t
;
```

---

```
+----------------------+
| 101.4663599769982749 |
+----------------------+
| 99.7017005854474491  |
+----------------------+
| 280.2769037130270610 |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: @PLearner: note that the cast to `money` would fail if `lc_monetary` uses a different currency symbol then `$` - you should really change those columns to `decimal` and store the currency in a different column